# Splash screen is not display after build on phonegap version cli 5.2.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have made splash screen for phonegap application but after upgrade my splash screen is not display i have written code in cofig file is as below and also i have added screen as per phonegap splash screen documentation. and also i have added default screen image in project.

```
  <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.abc.mobileapp" version="1.0.0" versionCode = "10">
  <name>abc</name>
  <description></description>
  <author email="admin@abc.com">abc</author>
  <content src="abc.html"/>
  <preference name='phonegap-version'/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <!--<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />-->
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <!--<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="6000" />-->

  <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>-->
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" source="plugins.cordova.io" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  version="0.2.12" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.11" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="0000000000000000" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" />
  </gap:plugin>

  <!-- Third party plugins -->
  <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
  <!--<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />-->

  <!--https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/2fdfde7/README.md
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" version="2.0.2" />-->

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>

  <gap:splash src="res/screen/default.png" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <!--<access origin="*xitstage-001-site3.mysitepanel.net"/>-->
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

What changeset i have to do with upgarde of phonegap application.

Comment: Where is the code that declares your splash screens? I do not see it. Please post your entire `config.xml` not the pieces

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 i have edited my Question you can find my config file. in code.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" /> this plugin is not working is any updation in it how can i update plugin.

Comment: This appears to be it: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing " source="npm" version="5.0.4">` The repository is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing). This is a link to the [plugin search engine](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=) Best of Luck –

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I have refere your repository & plugin search link i have a plugin <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0"><param name="APP_ID" value="998855950166112" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" />
  </gap:plugin> this plugin is for fb connected i have issue that its working on ios but not in android. i have search in all repository and your mention link but i didn't get. is this issue for not updating plugin i hv search updation plugin but didn't get it.can you give me guidence for this i am new bee in phonegap so i hv asked you again. thanks

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not being clear. You are using an OLD version 0.9.0 and you are NOT using the new NPM source. I am giving you a new version - which is now `version=5.0.5`. If you are having an issue with the plugin NOT working as you expect it, then you need to discuss that with the author. **NOTE:** since i wrote that note on *Oct 19* a new version has come out. Your issue may be fixed. In any case, if you are having problems with the plugin, then you need to ask the author. Here is the [link again](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 i am having issue in this plugin <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0"><param name="APP_ID" value="998855950166112" /> <param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" /> </gap:plugin> that its working in ios but not in android.i have try to find update on npm but not geting & put resource as npm. if i put resource as npm than got build time error that resorce is not found on npm. so any other way to get latest update for plugin <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">. thanks for your reply.

Comment: That plugin is deprecated. READ [facebookConnectPlugin is not defined - PhoneGap Build & Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33326131/3255670) I have answered this question 4 times tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vatsal,
Okay, you have a quite a few mistakes that are common to developers new to Cordova/Phonegap.

First read, just the **BOLD** points in this document, because you will want to fix your stuff first, then get the finer details.

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

The ***FIRST THING*** you want to do is set a version for your compiler. For this read
**6. Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**

I QUOTE

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform (..)(and) If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading error.

BTWS, you are not lucky. Doing this will NOT fix the mistakes, but it is important. You can read the entire document *later* for a better understanding.

***NEXT THING*** you need to get [ALL your core plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html) from NPM from now on. And make sure to set the versions for this. For this read
**11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

As an example,  you need to source your splashscreen plugin as [`cordova-plugin-splashscreen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen). The entry in config.xml would look like this:

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="2.1.0" source="npm" />`

NOTE, the the different spelling for the name, and the higher version number.

**Update: 2016-02-11** As of 19 Nov, 2015, the statement is not longer true. You can use either `<plugin (...)>` or `<gap:plugin (...)>`. See the [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/) for details.
<s>ALSO, if you are using *Phonegap Build*, then the examples I am giving you are okay. If you are using Cordova CLI or Phonegap CLI, you do not use `gap:plugin`.</s>

If you are using a CLI, then read **6.** again - it has the answer on how to use versions with plugins. But be aware, her examples are for the non-NPM, so the correct names are in [NPM repository](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html) from now on.

One last thing, I have no way to check your images. So, you MAY not get the splash screens to show up. I have a demo you can check here: [Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test). However, it is built on version `phonegap-version=3.5.0`. So, you can check your file paths and names, but not the code. Also, that code repository has notes on why the filenames need to be what they are.

I know some of this is confusing, so just make the changes, then we might need to walk through it again.

Best of Luck

Comment: Thank you for your great support and i will put all your  suggestion keep in my mind.

Comment: From where i can find updated pluginn if any source site or any document please provide.

Comment: <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" /> this plugin is not working  is any updation in it how can i update plugin.

Comment: This appears to be it: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing " source="npm" version="5.0.4">` The repository is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing).  This is a link to the [plugin search engine](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=) Best of Luck